# TortoiseGit client User info

Tags: tortoisegit

I am using TortoiseGit 2.3.0.0 on Windows 7 and GitHub enterprise. The repository is created on GitHub server which is accessible from the TortoiseGit client.
The GitHub repository is created as private for limited User access.
The issue I'm facing is, from the TortoiseGit Settings/Git/Edit global .gitconfig screen the User can change the "User name" and "email" info and Commit/Push the file to the GitHub repository. Resulting the Blame/History report with the new User info. What I am looking for …always take the Windows MS User ID as the User at the Tortoise client level that match with the GitHub account.
Anything I can do at the TortoiseGit client level to authenticate User from the Windows User name only and not allowing the user to modify the .gitconfig file directly. Please help.